# racket - calculate polynomial function

Tags: racket

I'm trying to wite a function `eval/x` that consumes a polynomial expression `ex` and a Num `val` that represents the current value of x, and produces the result of evaluating the expression when the value is used for x . For example:

```
(eval/x (make-pnode '+ 11 12) 159) => 23
(eval/x 'x 66) => 66
(eval/x (make-pnode '+ (make-pnode '* 'x -7) 3) -2) => 17
(eval/x (make-pnode '* 'x (make-pnode '+ 'x 1)) 5) => 30
```

I know how to evaluate an expression but I don't know how to put the value of x in the expression. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot

```
(define-struct pnode (op arg1 arg2))
(define (eval ex val)
  (cond
    [(number? ex) ex]
    [else (local
            [(define operation (pnode-op ex))
             (define left (eval (pnode-arg1 ex)))]
             (define right (eval (pnode-arg2 ex)))]
            (cond
              [(symbol=? operation '+) (+ left right)]
              [(symbol=? operation '-) (- left right)]
              [(symbol=? operation '*) (* left right)]
              [(symbol=? operation '/) (/ left right)]))]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it there. Simply add an additional case, if you find a symbol then return the value - and make sure to pass it along in the recursion:

```
(define (eval/x ex val)
  (cond
    [(number? ex) ex]
    [(symbol? ex) val] ; add this line
    [else (local
            [(define operation (pnode-op ex))
             (define left (eval/x (pnode-arg1 ex) val))
             (define right (eval/x (pnode-arg2 ex) val))]
            (cond
              [(symbol=? operation '+) (+ left right)]
              [(symbol=? operation '-) (- left right)]
              [(symbol=? operation '*) (* left right)]
              [(symbol=? operation '/) (/ left right)]))]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(eval/x (make-pnode '+ 11 12) 159)
=> 23
(eval/x 'x 66)
=> 66
(eval/x (make-pnode '+ (make-pnode '* 'x -7) 3) -2)
=> 17
(eval/x (make-pnode '* 'x (make-pnode '+ 'x 1)) 5)
=> 30
```